# Smarty: How to get the name of the loaded template file in smarty plugin

Tags: plugins, smarty

How to get the name of the loaded template file in smarty plugin?

Comment: What do you mean by "check"? Please be more specific

Comment: I want to know what template file that loaded this smarty plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Smarty 3 then the template object gets passed as last parameter to any plugin function:

```
 smarty_function_foo($params, $smarty, $template)
```

You can get the filepath with:

```
$template->getTemplateFilepath();
```

It should always be passed in as the last function, so for a block function it would be:

```
smarty_block_foo($params, $content, $smarty, $repeat, $template)
```

Comment: $template variable is empty. how to know which version of smarty i have?

Comment: It will probably be in your Smarty.class file somewhere near the top - or just ask the guy that installed it.